# How to access IteratorResult value?

Tags: typescript, generator

I'm very new to TypeScript and having a hard time figuring a problem.

Let's say I have a function that yields another function like below.

```
function sayHello() {
    return {
        name: 'mike'
    }
};
function* test() {
    yield(sayHello);
}
```

I'm trying to access `name` property in my test, but getting the following error message.

`Property 'name' does not exist on type 'void | (() => { name: string; })'. Property 'name' does not exist on type 'void'.`

This is my test code

```
const a = test();
a.next().value.name
```

Is there a way to indicate that `value` object is returned from `sayHello` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue that you are facing is the way `yield` works. Here is the [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield) with a nice example.

Bottom line, when you call `next` of the generator, the function pauses and returns whatever is on the `yield` keyword, and resumes again when we call `next` again, only to pause on the next `yield` until the function returns eventually.

In your case,

```ts
function* test() {
    yield(sayHello);
}
```

You have two stops, one when function yields at line #2 and returns the function, the next time the function's natural return which is `void`. So, your function may return either the function or `void`, hence the return type as you correctly pointed is:

```ts
void | (() => { name: string; })
```

Let's see the problem, with this information. When you say,

```ts
const a = test();
const value = a.next().value
```

Typescript cannot guarantee whether value is the function or void, because it does not track the the number of times next() is called and which `next()` would result into the function and which into `void`. So, the responsibility is on the developer.

This is how you do it:

```ts
function sayHello() {
    return {
        name: 'mike'
    }
};
function* test() {
    yield(sayHello);
}

const a = test();
const v = a.next().value;

// We need to ensure that this v is not void, 
// which leaves it being the function
if(v){
  const r = v().name;
  console.log(r) // works!
}

// Now that it has yielded, this would be undefined
console.log(a.next().value)
```

Link to TS Playground: https://tsplay.dev/mL9VbW